# Mockito UnfinishedStubbingException, but spy exists

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I'm using JUnit 4.12 and Mockito 1.10.19 and I'm stuck with a Mockito issue that I cannot explain.

I'm creating an abstract class (as I did in the past) which set ups a **spy** on an object of type `BaseFunction` (an abstract class I have in my project)

```
public abstract class AbstractFunctionTestCase<F extends BaseFunction> {

    @Rule
    public JUnitSoftAssertions softly = new JUnitSoftAssertions();

    protected F function;

    /**
     * Return the real function here
     * @return
     */
    protected abstract F functionInstance();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        function = Mockito.spy(functionInstance());

        Mockito.doReturn("Bla").when(function).getDescription();
    }

}
```

Then I just extend the abstract class as folows

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyFunctionTest extends AbstractFunctionTestCase<MyFunction> {

    @Override
    protected MyFunction functionInstance() {
        return new MyFunction();
    }

    @Test
    public void myEmptyTest() {
      // Nothing here, for real!
    }

}
```

When I run method `myEmptyTest` in IntelliJ I get

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.company.functions.AbstractFunctionTestCase.setUp(AbstractFunctionTestCase.java:31)
```

Strange to me, is that I've checked that I have a spy inside `setUp()` method, by calling

```
new MockUtil().isSpy(function)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that methods from parent classes cannot be mocked.

The solution that I used was to declare method `getDescription()` inside an interface and make the parent class implementing this interface.

E.g.

```
public interface Function {

  String getDescription();

}
```

and then

```
public abstract class BaseFunction implements Function {

   @Override
   public String getDescription(){
      return "bla";
   }
}
```